# Flutter device daemon #1: process exited during startup

Tags: flutter, dart, kernel, daemon

the dart path is correct, the environment variable also fine but I can not figure what went wrong, I can not create or run flutter projects. I don't know what is the is please help me figure out this.

[image]

Comment: can you run `flutter --version` and `flutter doctor`,check everything installed correctly, and share the screenshot of above commands@Sangeeth

Comment: Please, [edit] the question and replace **image** with the **text** it contains. See also [ask].

Comment: Thank you, guys! @Assassin  Tsyvarev, I tried different methods to solve the issue, and finally replacing the flutter SDK zip file made it work.  I really appreciate your effort! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

There could be chances that you've installed a Flutter before and Flutter took parts of the old version to initialize. Here is a [related GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67222).

Usually a [workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67222#issuecomment-703127102) here is to remove or delete `flutter_tools.stamp`.

```
rm FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp
```

But for most, [replacing the existing Flutter SDK](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67222#issuecomment-777694406) with the new one from the [Flutter website](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) works like charm.